# Is there any way to get AWS resource usage by tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm creating resources in AWS (mainly EC2, EBS disks and S3 space) for our customers as part of our SaaS product. I would like to be able to get the usage of those resources to be able to send that usage to Stripe to charge and invoice my users.

I was thinking that tagging would be a good way to group resources of a specific customer, so if I put this tag to all its resources:  `"Customer" => "cust_id_4894168127"`, then I could do this in pseudo-code API call:

`https://www.aws_api_url.com/api/getResourceUsage?Tag=Customer/cust_id_4894168127&From=2020/02/02%To=2020/03/03`

And the API would return something like:

```
{
  [
    "ResourceID": "8hf8972g8h9",
    "ResourceType": "EC2",
    "UsageHours": 231,
  ],
  [
    "ResourceID": "09j05h05hj",
    "ResourceType": "EBS disk",
    "DiskSpaceUsedGB": 200,
  ],
  [
    "ResourceID": "h87f3go2f2",
    "ResourceType": "S3 space",
    "SpaceUsedGB": 500,
  ],
}
```

I would like to get everything that Amazon is going to charge me in order to charge the customer for all that concepts. If I can't find a way to do it, I'll have to store all the user actions in my database, then calculate the time the EC2 was running, etc.

Do you know of a way to do it with the SDK API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get-resources](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html) function with tag filters to get all resources.

An example of this is below

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tag-filters Key=Customer,Values=cust_id_4894168127
```

This would return the Arns of all resources along with any tags attached, from here you would need to call the API for that service to get the metadata you need about it.

For billing you can make use of [cost allocation tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) to identify the charges for a specific customer.

Comment: This seems like a step in the good direction, but:


1- With the "cost allocation tags" it seems like I'm going to get the cost in dollars, but is there a way I can get it in usage units? I mean, we've said to our customers that each hour of our product in an EC2 costs i.e. $2 / hour, so it would be good to know how many hours the EC2 has been running.

2- What do you mean by "to get the metadata you need about it"? May I get the usage in hours/gigabytes as I was just asking?